# alpinejs image slider first slide repeating twice and last slide not defined

Tags: laravel-blade, alpine.js

I image slide on homepage http://steklo.gq/ made using alpine and there are two strange things:

1. First slide **design-5.jpg** is repeating twice on the page
2. It gives me error in console **Uncaught ReferenceError: slide is not defined** on the last slide. However image exists and last slide defined the same way as all other slides. So I cannot understand what is the problem.

```
Alpine Error: "ReferenceError: slide is not defined"

Expression: "slide.img"
Element: <img x-bind:src=​"slide.img" class=​"h-148 w-full lg:​h-224 object-cover" src=​"/​storage/​thumbs_xl/​slider/​1912501_1600x1200.jpg">​
handleError @ app.js:18
tryCatch @ app.js:18
saferEval @ app.js:19
evaluateReturnExpression @ app.js:187
handleAttributeBindingDirective @ app.js:67
(anonymous) @ app.js:186
resolveBoundAttributes @ app.js:186
initializeElement @ app.js:180
(anonymous) @ app.js:178
(anonymous) @ app.js:177
walk @ app.js:16
walk @ app.js:16
walk @ app.js:16
walk @ app.js:16
walk @ app.js:16
walkAndSkipNestedComponents @ app.js:176
initializeElements @ app.js:178
(anonymous) @ app.js:192
(anonymous) @ app.js:191
attributes (async)
addClass @ app.js:926
Slick.init @ app.js:2702
Slick @ app.js:2646
$.fn.slick @ app.js:2798
(anonymous) @ app.js:367
```

```html
    <x-slot name="mainslider">
        <div class="mainslider_container absolute w-full h-full top-0" id="main_slider"
          x-data="{
            slides: [
              { id:1, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/design-5.jpg', text: 'Офисные перегородки <br> в стиле LOFT', textclass: 'top-1/4 text-white', buttonclass: '' },
              { id:2, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/design-7.jpg', text: 'Межкомнатные раздвижные <br> перегородки', textclass: 'bottom-1/4 text-white', buttonclass: 'text-white' },
              { id:3, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/img_20171230_191642.jpg', text: 'Лестничные ограждения <br> из закалённого стекла', textclass: 'top-1/3 text-white', buttonclass: 'text-white' },
              { id:4, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/2018-03-09-20-29-24.jpg', text: 'Цельностеклянные перегородки', textclass: 'bottom-1/4 text-white', buttonclass: 'text-white' },
              { id:5, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/peregorodka-47.jpg', text: 'Пескоструйные рисунки <br> на стекле', textclass: 'bottom-52 text-white', buttonclass: 'text-white' },
              { id:6, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/dsc_0003.jpg', text: 'Стеклянные ограждения <br> балконов и террас', textclass: 'top-28', buttonclass: '' },
              { id:7, img: '/storage/thumbs_xl/slider/1912501_1600x1200.jpg', text: 'Стеклянные перегородки для ресторанов', textclass: 'top-28 text-white', buttonclass: '' },
            ]
          }" 
          x-effect="console.log(slide)"
        >

          <template x-for="slide in slides" :key="slide.id">
            <div class="mainslider_item relative">
              <img x-bind:src="slide.img" class="h-148 w-full lg:h-224 object-cover">
              <div class="mainslider_item_text absolute w-full flex justify-center py-4 text-3xl font-bold" x-bind:class="slide.textclass" x-html="slide.text">
              </div>
              <div class="mainslider_item_button absolute top-12 right-0 w-1/2 flex justify-center" x-bind:class="slide.buttonclass">
                <x-modules.link-button  
                    link="#" text="Заказать звонок" icon="phone-ringing-outline" 
                    style="black-outline" class="w-48 p-1.5" 
                    @click.prevent="contactForm()"
                />                
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>

        </div>

    </x-slot>
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```js
require('./includes/script.js');
```

**resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```js
window.carousel = require('slick-carousel');
```

**resources/js/includes/script.js**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  /*===== slick carousel modal plugin =====*/
  /*============= main slider =============*/
  $('#main_slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    nextArrow: '<div class="main__arrow arrow-next"></div>',
    prevArrow: '<div class="main__arrow arrow-prev"></div>',
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false
        }
      }       
    ]                
  });
  /*===== FINISH slick carousel modal plugin =====*/
});
```

Comment: I have alpinejs extension for chrome devtools bar and it doesn't give me any error

Comment: You should not use objects at `:key` but strings or integers, e.g. `:key="slide.img"`, otherwise the code looks ok. If you put `x-effect="console.log(slide)"` somewhere into the component, what does it print to the console before the error message?

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion, but no help. You can check on webpage that `x-effect="console.log(slide)"` doesn't give any value in console. I see only error there

Comment: Could you upgrade Alpine.js to 3.x? Maybe it's and old bug.

Comment: Upgrade Alpine.js to 3.10.2. Error still there. And now I have 2 more warnings in console

Comment: Very strange. Could you put the `x-effect="console.log(slide)"` inside the loop, e.g. on the `img`?

Comment: Now I see some additional info in console, but it doesn't help. And instead of first picture I see blank picture on the page

Comment: Do you see the correct image paths in the console?

Comment: Yes. Paths are correct and I see all 7 pictures in the slider, but for unknown reason I have 8 dots (and 8 slides). So I see one additional blank slide.

Comment: and this blank slide in the start of slider

Comment: A checked the source of the site and it's very strange. It seems the 0th slide is the raw Alpine.js `<template>` code. I think the origin of the problem is at the slider initialization, maybe you need to call [`$nextTick`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick) to wait for rendering, then call the slider's init function. Could you share the way you init the slider?

Comment: It is done using slick slider plugin. JS code added in the topic.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, it caused by slick slider when it clones the slide content. During that it somehow triggers Alpine.js to rerender with errors. My recommendation is just to generate slick's content on the backend with Laravel. That will skip the cloning issue.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how to do that? You mean that I should remove `<template/>` from laravel view into alpine component or what?

Comment: Sure. I suppose you have the list of the images in the DB. So instead of creating an Alpine.js component and looping over the slides with `<template x-for...` do the same on the backend with Laravel, e.g. `@foreach ($slides as $slide)`. The output should be the same as with Alpine.js. After that slick-slider should work since no Alpine.js code will remain at the generated list of slides.

Comment: Actually I didn't have list of these images in DB, because I wanted to make code for the slider as short as possible and I like the idea to keep code of the whole component inside `<template>` tag. Now I replace it with `@foreach ($slides as $slide)` and problem with the first blank picture disappeared. The only disadvantage is that now code for slider module on homepage spreaded in many files: migration, model, controller etc. But anyway thank you for your help.